# hypen in MVC 3 routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, custom-routes

Here is my desired url format: **/product-24-hid-35wh4-cx-dsgtx**

How can I map this URL to my action method:

```
public ActionResult Product(int id)
```

Here is my routing code:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
       "ProductDetail",
       "product-{id}-{name}",
        new { controller = "product", action = "detail", name = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "SphereLight.Controllers" }
  );
```

However, it does not work; I used phil haack's routedebugger to test this route, and below is the result:

```
 Key    Value
 name   dsgtx 
 id         24-hid-35wh4-cx 
 controller product 
 action detail
```

Only *id = 24* is correct.

In one word, I need a route to match:

```
   /product-24
   /product-24-
   /product-24-hid-35wh4-cx-dsgtx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add constraints in your MapRoute:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
       "ProductDetail",
       "product-{id}-{name}",
        new { controller = "product", action = "detail", name = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = @"\d+" }, // <-- change it for @"[^-]+", if it can be non-digit
        new string[] { "SphereLight.Controllers" }
  );
```

**UPDATE:**
Finally got it.
The main problem is that you can't use parameters which contains the same separator.
For example, the example above will work with `/product-24-nm`, but not with `product-24-nm-smth`.

So, let's try this solution:
I've made it on the default routing, you can make it your way

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
        new MyRouteHandler()
        ).RouteHandler = new MyRouteHandler();
```

Implementation of `MyRouteHandler`:

```
public class MyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    private static readonly Regex ProductPattern = new Regex(@"product\-(\d+)\-?(.*)");

    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var match = ProductPattern.Match(requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());
        if (match.Length > 0)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Detail";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = match.Groups[1].Value;
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["name"] = match.Groups[2].Value;
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

So, the main idea is to check if the values matches our pattern `product-id-name` in the handler, and not trying to make it in `MapRoute`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: does not work , route debugger result is {controller:product-26-hid-35wh11-cx-dsgtx,action:index} , if disable mvc's default route , the debugger result is {any:product-24-hid-35wh4-cx-dsgtx ,
controller:NotFound ,action:NotFound}

Comment: Hmm... And what if add `id = UrlParameter.Optional`?

Comment: i'm afraid not , id is the key to find the product

Comment: Find a solution, but it's something strange with parser. See update of post.